# Emacs shell exits after executing a cygwin command

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell

Windows, Emacs 27.2.

I execute fairly simple cygwin commands from an Emacs shell - first tried unzip then backed up to test ls - and the shell exits.  Why?

Comment: Downloaded and ran the latest windows version, 29.1_2, and it still has the same problem.  Something as simple as a cygwin ls in an Emacs shell and the command executes, then the shell exits.

Comment: You may need to provide more info, to specify just what you did.